# Spell check contents of Rich Text Content Control

Tags: ms-office, word-2013

I am having an issue with Word 2013 and spell checking the contents of Rich Text Content Controls.

I am currently working on a project where text is inserted (via a Word Add-In) into a pre-defined document template which makes use of Rich Text Content Controls. The inserting of the data into the content controls all works great, but I am having an issue where the newly inserted text within the content controls is not being spell checked by Word 2013.

I have read numerous posts on line which suggest that 'grouping' the content controls in the document resolves the issue, but haven't been able to implement this fix.

Text outwith the content controls is being spell checked, but any text within the content controls is not.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open Word 2013 and create a new blank document.
2. Ensure that the **DEVELOPER** tab is enabled (if not, see instructions [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-the-Developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45))
3. On the **DEVELOPER** tab, enable **Design Mode** under the **Controls** group.
4. Still on the **DEVELOPER** tab, under **Controls**, add a new **Rich Text Content Control**.
5. Amend the default "Click here to enter text." so that it contains a spelling mistake.
6. On the **DEVELOPER** tab, exit **Design Mode**.
7. On the **REVIEW** tab, choose **Spelling & Grammar**. You should observe that the deliberate spelling mistake within the content control is not recognised.

Answer (score 0):

James, the text you edit in the Rich Text Content Control is what is called the Placeholder Text. This text is to be defined by the 'content' developer.

This text won't be part of the Spelling & Grammar review as the Placeholder Texts are 'constants' defined by the developer, hence the reason why they are under the Developer tab.

So it is advised to first put the texts that you want to use in a Placeholder in a normal document, do the spell check and copy them over and apply to the Placeholder Text.

I think it is fairly reasonable not to include the Placeholder texts in Spelling & Grammar as:

- It will take time to process the fixed assets
- End users may not have access to the Placeholder Texts to edit the 'mistakes'

Comment: Hi Maarten. The way we are using Content Controls is slightly different from what you describe. We have a document template which features items such as Name: {RichTextCC} _Name is inserted here by a Custom Word Add-In_ {/RichTextCC}. We are finding that the values which are inserted by the Word Add-In are not being spell checked, but from your explanation, I now understand why. Thanks for clarifying.